# Problem in receiving SignalR notification in Angular project sent from background worker in .NET Core with aspnetboilerplate

Tags: angular, .net-core, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-core-signalr

I am working with ASP.NET Boilerplate project for .NET Core and Angular. In my .NET Core project, I have a background worker. My goal is to send notification to the user in every 2 milliseconds. I have created a Notification Hub with SignalR.

Here is the hub code:

```
public class MyTestHub : Hub, ITransientDependency
{
    public IAbpSession AbpSession { get; set; }
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    public MyTestHub()
    {
        AbpSession = NullAbpSession.Instance;
        Logger = NullLogger.Instance;
    }

    public async Task SendMessage(string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("getMessage", string.Format("User {0}: {1}", AbpSession.UserId, message));
    }

    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
        Logger.Debug("A client connected to MyChatHub: " + Context.ConnectionId);
    }

    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        Logger.Debug("A client disconnected from MyChatHub: " + Context.ConnectionId);
    }
}
```

I have registered the Hub in the `startup` file:

[image]

And here is my background worker code, which is sending a notification to all user in every 2 milliseconds:

```
public class SendingMessageWorker : PeriodicBackgroundWorkerBase, ISingletonDependency
{   
    private readonly IHubContext<MyTestHub> _notificationHubContext;
    
    public SendingMessageWorker(AbpTimer timer,
        IHubContext<MyTestHub> notificationHubContext) : base(timer)
    {
        Timer.Period = 2000;        
        _notificationHubContext = notificationHubContext;
    }

    [UnitOfWork]
    protected override void DoWork()
    {
        using (CurrentUnitOfWork.DisableFilter(AbpDataFilters.MayHaveTenant))
        {           
            string message = "Hi! This is a sample message " + Clock.Now;
            AsyncHelper.RunSync(() => _notificationHubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("App.SimpleMessage", message));
        }
    }
}
```

I tested the background worker with Hub in the chrome inspection network tab and can see that the hub sending the message constantly.

[image]

Now with the help of this [link](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/SignalR-AspNetCore-Integration) from ASP.NET Boilerplate website, I have added the below code in my Angular project. In the `app.component.ts` file, in `ngOnInit` function I have added this code:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    
    SignalRAspNetCoreHelper.initSignalR(() => {
        var chatHub = null;

        abp.signalr.startConnection(abp.appPath + 'signalr-myTestHub', function (connection) {
            chatHub = connection; // Save a reference to the hub
            connection.on('getMessage', function (message) { // Register for incoming messages
                console.log('Received the message: ' + message);
            });
        }).then(function (connection) {
            abp.log.debug('Connected to myTestHub server!');
            abp.event.trigger('myTestHub.connected');
        });

        abp.event.on('myTestHub.connected', function (notification) { // Register for connect event
            console.log("Log: ", notification);
            alert(notification)
            chatHub.invoke('sendMessage', "Hi everybody, I'm connected to the chat!"); // Send a message to the server
        });
    });     
}
```

Now each time the background worker sends the push notification, in the frontend application I should see an Alert Message and a Log in the Browser. Because I have the below code in Angular:

```
abp.event.on('myTestHub.connected', function (notification) { 
    console.log("Log: ", notification);
    alert(notification)
    chatHub.invoke('sendMessage', "Hi everybody, I'm connected to the chat!"); 
});
```

But I don't see any alert message or log in the console tab of the browser. Only once when I refresh the page an alert appears with undefined value. This alert only shows at the first time when the page Loads. But I am expecting the alert message in every 2 seconds without the page refresh.

[image]

Can anyone help me to understand where is the problem and how to solve this. I am very new to aspnetboilerplate and SignalR.

Answer (score 1):

When the client create the connection and connected the hub, we are using `abp.event.trigger('myTestHub.connected');` to call the registered event `myTestHub.connected`.

We can see there is no params in `abp.event.trigger('myTestHub.connected');`, that why the `notification` is undefined.

**My test result.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @mnu-nasir, you didn’t get my point, I just point why you get undefined error. Now the method will be triggered when the connection established, because you define it after connecting.

Comment: @mnu-nasir You need move the abp.event.trigger to connection.on(getMessage), then the client get messages it will alert the messages.